# How I can pass a SQLDatabaseHelper object between activities?

Tags: java, android

I have an object SQLDatabaseHelper contains methods onCreate , onUpgrade and others but I can't send the object to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass it between activities, per se.

1.Use [Service locator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern)
(not recommended)

```
public class Locator {
    public SQLDatabaseHelper getDbHelper() {

    }
}
```

2.Use a dependency injection framework like Dagger. Something like this:

```
@Component(modules = {DbModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}

@Module
public class DbModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public static SQLDatabaseHelper dbHelper() {
        //create your helper here
    }
}

public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Injector.init(this);
    }
}

public class Injector {
    private static AppComponent appComponent;

    public static void init(Application app) {
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .application(app)
                .build();
    }

    public static AppComponent appComponent() {
        return appComponent;
    }
}

public class MainActivity {
    protected void onCreate() {
        Injector.appComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```